# How to create posts inside another posts like below link?

Tags: wordpress

**Hi, This is my blog posts** 
http://dailyviraltimes.com/dvt/the-original-american-pie-cast-then-now/

**I want this post to work like this** 
http://theviraldance.com/american-pie-movie-sales-famous-actors_safez/
one celebrity per page with next prev. i don't know how is this working. will you please guide me how i can create my post like this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type;

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

between your contents. Its default wordpress function. For the detail of styling navigation you can check [Styling Page-Links](https://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links)